# I want to know how to execute CONNECT BY REGEXP in Google Big query

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, oracle-sqldeveloper, connect-by

I have following statement in oracle sql I want to run this in Google Big Query.

```
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(VALUE, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
```

How can I run above code in Big query?

Comment: BigQuery DOES NOT support CONNECT BY - meantime if you can formulate your question in sense of what you have as an input data and what you expect as an output  - we can try to help you. Ideally you should also provide what you tried by yourself - usually (even it is in many cases not even close to what will be the answer) it helps in understanding your case better. Anyway - good simple example along with explaining the logic is short way to get good answer

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing here - but usually this construct is used for so called string decomposition

So, in BigQuery you can use SPLIT(value) or REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(value, r'[^,]+') for this as in below examples

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '1,2,3,4,5,6,7' AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'a,b,c,d'
)
SELECT id, SPLIT(value) value
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

or

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '1,2,3,4,5,6,7' AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'a,b,c,d'
)
SELECT id, REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(value, r'[^,]+') value
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

both above query will return

```
Row id  value    
1   1   1    
        2    
        3    
        4    
        5    
        6    
        7    
2   2   a    
        b    
        c    
        d
```

Here, as you can see - value in each row gets split into array of elements but still in the same row

To flatten result you can further use UNNEST() as in below examples

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '1,2,3,4,5,6,7' AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'a,b,c,d'
)
SELECT id, value
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(SPLIT(value)) value
```

or

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, '1,2,3,4,5,6,7' AS value UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'a,b,c,d'
)
SELECT id, value
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(value, r'[^,]+')) value
```

both return below result (with all extracted elements in separate row)

```
Row id  value    
1   1   1    
2   1   2    
3   1   3    
4   1   4    
5   1   5    
6   1   6    
7   1   7    
8   2   a    
9   2   b    
10  2   c    
11  2   d
```